# djang orm filter with self date column

Tags: django, filter, orm

i have a question.

my model is like below.

```
depart_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Depart Date"))
days = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Day"))
```

and i want filter my data depart_date + days >= today

is it possible using orm query?

it is so simple when i use raw query below ( when i using oracle )

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE = WHERE depart_date + days >= > TO_DATE('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

than you for your help

Comment: You can compare in ORM with `depart_date__lte=TO_DATE(...) - days`

Answer (score 1):

You can try your luck with [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) object and [expression wrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions):

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, ExpressionWrapper, F

YourModel.objects.annotate(days_delta=ExpressionWrapper(timezone.timedelta(seconds=1) * F("days"), output_field=DateTimeField()).annotate(final_date=ExpressionWrapper(F('depart_date') + F('days_delta'), output_field=DateTimeField())).filter(final_date__gte=timezone.now())
```

Also, you may need to use [value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) to wrap the timedelta expression part.

Note: this may not work on some DB engines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via extra step by using `.annotate()`.
For example, rough idea is:

```py
return (YourModel
       .objects
       .annotate(full_date=F("depart_date") + F("days"))
       .fitler(full_date__gte=timezone.now())
)
```

Comment: Doesn't this through an exception "Expression contains mixed types"?

Answer (score 0):

```
aim_date = depart_date - datetime.timedelta(days=7)


# if you want to get datas which earler than 7 days ago,maybe you can try this
obj_list=Customer.objects.filter(depart_date__lte=aim_date)
```

hope can help you!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to charnel.

i try to use your code but it's occured error

so, i edit your example code like this

```
model.objects.annotate(
        arrive_date=ExpressionWrapper(F('depart_date') + timedelta(days=1) * (F('day')),
                                      output_field=DateTimeField())).filter(arrive_date__gte={date})
```